# Does this socket bind fail? If so why?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, bind

(Why doesn't this code work?)

I'm learning Linux socket programming. The following code is based on an example at [this site](http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/manuals/lspe/snode=27.html) that I'm learning from:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  // Create a socket with domain AF_INET and type SOCK_STREAM.
  int sd_inet;
  if ( -1 == ( sd_inet = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) )
  {
    std::cout << "socket() failed." << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  // Create an AF_INET address.
  struct sockaddr_in si;
  memset( &si, 0, sizeof( si ) );
  si.sin_family = AF_INET;
  si.sin_port = htons( 9000 );
  const unsigned char addr[] = { 127, 0, 0, 23 }; // Local loopback.
  std::memcpy( &si.sin_addr.s_addr, addr, sizeof( addr ) );
  int si_len = sizeof( si );

  // Bind the address to the socket.
  if ( -1 == bind( sd_inet, (struct sockaddr*)&si, si_len ) )
  {
    std::cout << "bind() failed." << std::endl;
    close( sd_inet );
    return 1;
  }

  system( "netstat -pa --tcp 2>/dev/null " );
  close( sd_inet );

  return 0;
}
```

**Desired behavior**: The output of this program should display an entry for the bound socket created by this program.

**Problem/Question**: The output of `netstat` does not show the expected bound socket. Can someone please help identify what is wrong?

**What else I have tried**: I was unclear whether the `"127.0.0.23"` address should generically work, or if that was supposed to be a valid IP address that I have "assigned" to a network card on my box, so I experimented with assigning "127.0.0.1" and `htonl( INADDR_ANY )` to `si.sin_addr.s_addr`, as well as trying a `sin_port` value of `0`, but none of those experiments yielded different results.

Compiled with gcc 4.8.3.

Comment: `si.sin_addr.s_addr` is (probably) a 32-bit intreger, so whether your memcpy works will depend on the endianness of the machine. You should be using something like htons().

Comment: On failure (e.g. of `bind`) you should use `perror` (or some other `errno` related thing ....)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - I understand what you mean, but in the above code, `bind()` does not return -1 (i.e. does not fail), so no use in checking `errno` for the current state of the code.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - Not sure I follow why...`addr[]` is an `unsigned char` array, so its content isn't endian-dependent: it actually is in network byte order (i.e. big-endian order), so it should be formatted correctly for the `bind`, no?

Comment: @NeilButterworth - One other point: as I mentioned, I tried `htonl( INADDR_ANY )`, which aligns with your suggestion, but no change in behavior.

Comment: When I run your program using `htonl(INADDR_ANY)`, `lsof` shows `sock    0,7      0t0 248811876 can't identify protocol`

Comment: @NeilButterworth - fyi, that memcpy is legit; I checked the memory contents. Moreover, subsequent to the memcpy, if I `htonl()` it, the `bind()` then fails. So it's not the address endianness that's the problem.

Comment: @Barmar - I was unfamiliar with `lsof` but tried it now. When I try `lsof | grep "a.out"` with the code as-is (i.e. without `htonl(INADDR_ANY)`), then I see this entry: `a.out 25998 user 3u sock 0,6 0t0 32683949 protocol: TCP` . Does this mean the code works? If so, why does an entry show up in `lsof` but not `netstat`?

Comment: Probably because you never called `listen()`.

Comment: @Barmar - Sounds like you understand what's at play here. Would you be willing to elaborate in an answer? At the linked site I am learning from, the example text does not call `listen()` but implies that their similar/equivalent code should result in the expected output from `netstat`. I ran similar code using the `AF_LOCAL` domain, and in that case I did see expected output from `netstat` - is that because `listen()` is required for TCP sockets but not UDP sockets?

Comment: @Barmar - You hit the nail on the head! I added a call to `listen()` and I see my expected output from `netstat`. If you have anything more you can elaborate about what was behind this, I'd be grateful (and you'd get a point :) ). The text I was learning from was obviously deficient here.

Comment: Normally `netstat` only shows connected sockets. Adding `-a` makes it also show listening sockets. But until you do one of those things, the socket isn't in any meaningful state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call either `listen()` or `connect()` on the socket to get it into a state that shows up in `netstat`. After the block that calls `bind()`, add:

```
  if (-1 == listen(sd_inet, 5)) {
      std::cout << "listen() failed." <<std::endl;
      close(sd_inet);
      return 1;
  }
```

and then you'll see it:

```
tcp        0      0 *:9000                  *:*                     LISTEN      9912/testbind
```

Comment: I think the issue is that the socket isn't yet in *any* TCP state. It's waiting for you to do something that sets the state.

Comment: Confirming that I observe the desired behavior by implementing your code addition. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To add a *why* to Barmar's answer, although `netstat --help` doesn't explain this, [the manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) does:

> **`-a, --all`**
>   Show both listening and non-listening (for TCP this means established connections) sockets

That is, "all" is a bit of a misnomer.

Your socket is neither listening (because you did not call `listen()` yet) nor "non-listening" according to the above definition (because you did not `connect()` anywhere either).

Therefore, it is not listed.

You would see it in `lsof` output in its embryonic state; quoting Barmar, it'll be something like:

> ```
> sock 0,7 0t0 248811876 can't identify protocol
> ```

Comment: @StoneThrow: I'm only ever a stone's throw away. :)